# Uninstall PHP-FPM (7.0) UBUNTU or reset configuration

Tags: php, ubuntu

I want to know how to uninstall `PHP7.0-FPM` From ubuntu 16.x

I tried removing it but the config is the same when I reinstall, how do I completely undo the changes I have made in the configs?

Comment: You could try [apt-get purge <pkg>](http://askubuntu.com/a/231568).

Answer (score 9):

The command `apt-get remove` will remove only the binary , you should use the `purge` command to remove the needed package with its dependencies and configuration file  as follows :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php-fpm
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge php-fpm
```

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Fixed a problem I had but be sure you really want to remove packages in the last command